# Adjust page content to the browser window width

Tags: html, css

I am working on a page where it needs to adjust to the width of the browser. When the browser window is stretched, the 'content' needs to grow (got that part working!) and when the window shrinks beyond a minimum width, the page structure needs to stay intact. So I should be able to scroll to see the 'sidebar' but it jumps down. Please help!

Here is what I have tried so far -

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:400px;
    background: #fff;
    padding:20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;">

    <div id="content" style="width:54%;
    float:left;
    min-width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin-right:3%;
    border:1px solid green;">
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar" style="width:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:3%;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid yellow;">
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: give a jsfiddle it will be clear to answer

Comment: Here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/tssCQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `min-width: 850px;` on the wrapper. Or whatever you want your minimum to be. Put your sidebar first and float it right:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdares/JEVfC/

```
#wrapper {
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:400px;
    background: #fff;
    padding:20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    min-width: 850px;
}
#content {
    min-width:400px;
    width: 54%;
    height:400px;
    margin-right:3%;
    border:1px solid green;
}
#sidebar {
    width:350px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:3%;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid yellow;
}
```

Also - if you don't want the gap between them to grow, set a `margin-left: 3%;` on `#sidebar`. On `#content`, remove the `width: 54%;` and add `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Updated - just realized your side bar was supposed to be on the right.

Comment: Thank you! Now the sidebar stays up there but when the window is stretched, the content needs to grow. Any suggestion?

Comment: Was that what you were after?

Comment: Yes, pretty much! Just added float:left; to #content to always keep the sidebar next to content. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiarized with `@media` query or **Responsive Web Design**? Is maded in **CSS3**. This might help you to design your web dependely the size of the viwer's screen.

**How It Works**

You need to set the maximum and the minimun `with` property, dependely **(or not)** the size of the screen (using `@media`query). Check [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

**Solving your problem**
*HTML*

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 90%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:400px;
    background: #fff;
    padding:20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#content {
    max-width: 54%;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:400px;
    margin-right:3%;
    border:1px solid green;
}
#sidebar {
    with: 100%;
    max-width:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:3%;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid yellow;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yFhH2/)

Answer (score 0):

you could define a minimum width:

```
#wrapper {
 min-width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your div class, add the minimum width parameter to the style so that it does not shrink below that! You can do that like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:400px;
    background: #fff;
    padding:20px;
    min-width:500px; /* Enter whatever minimum width you want your page to be */
    border: 1px solid blue;">

    <div id="content" style="width:54%;
    float:left;
    min-width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin-right:3%;
    border:1px solid green;">
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar" style="width:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:3%;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid yellow;">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for? [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/tssCQ/2/)

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:400px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;">

    <div id="content" style="width: 54%;
    float: left;
    height:400px;
    margin-right: 3%;
    border: 1px solid green;"> Content </div>

    <div id="sidebar-left" style="  width: 31%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3%;
    height:400px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;"> Sidebar </div>
</div>
```